# Does the linear transformation of a zero vector always map onto the zero vector in another set?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For the standard vector space this is true of course, but are there any examples where this wouldn't be true?

Comment: One of the properties of a linear transformation is that T(s*v)=s*T(v) for any scalar s and vector v.  What is s=0?

Comment: What is the standard vector space?

Comment: @Oiler I mean a vector space defined by standard scalar multiplication and addition.

Comment: Do yo know the axioms of vector space?

Comment: @Sithe Well all vector spaces satisfy "standard scalar multiplication and addition" these are outlined in the axioms of a vector space. If you have a linear transformation between vector spaces then yes, the zero vector always maps to the zero vector.